# Android onClick event fails

Tags: android, onclick

I'm having some problem here with android + java + cloud. My onCLick event is working only one time

The event only work again when i go back to the last screen and enter again in the screen that i made searchs in the cloud...

Comment: The code used is: Code used: http://pastebin.com/nnKqzLZ9

Answer (score 0):

I think you are only allowed to call setContentView() once. Since you are doing it in your click listener that might be why it is failing after the first time.

Edit: What does it do when it fails? Force close? nothing? something unexpected?

Comment: setContentView() is only called when a button in other screen is pressed. Then, in the new screen appears more three buttons ( the buttons that make searchs in the cloud).